# lost and important file for python 34

Tags: windows-8, python, chmod

My AVG internet security deleted a file called: C:\Python34\pythonw.exe

I now cannot access IDLE or even re-install python 3.4, although I can access the command line. How would you chown that file?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "chown" under Windows? How would you "chown" a file that was deleted? Why can't you reinstall Python?

Comment: when I try to re-install python 34, it keep son returning this:error writing to file: C:\Python34\pythonw.exe. Verify you have access to that directory.

Comment: Please edit your question and answer all my questions. We can't provide a comprehensive answer without these answers.

Comment: well I was told to chown the executable by a friend, but then couldn't find how to do so

Comment: chown is not a valid windows command your friend is mistaken don't listen to his advice or ask him for the correct Windows command. changing the owner won't solve the problem, changing the folder permissions would, which is well documented

Comment: AVG have deleted that file, and I'm not sure how to access that file. Is there any way to just install a single file?

Answer (score 1):

AVG probably detects a *false positive*, ie. it accuses a perfectly good file of being a virus. It happens sometimes and it's not a reason to worry.

First add Python directory to AVG's excluded folders list. That will prevent it for scanning it for viruses and will suppress false positives.

Then check AVG's quarantine. It's possible that the file wasn't deleted but quarantined. In that case you should be able to restore it back to its original location.

If you can't restore the file from quarantine, then you'll probably be able to reinstall Python without any problems after excluding its folder from scanning.